# Performance Counters Registry key missing in Windows ServerCore container (azure application insights jar)

Tags: java, containers, azure-application-insights, performancecounter, windows-container

I'm trying to get the [azure application insights java agent](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java) to work in my Java Application. This works fine on my dev machine and in a VM but I get errors when I try it in a local Windows container.

```
[2021-06-24 06:04:48,844] INFO  [PerformanceCounterContainer-0] out.b(a.java) 2021-06-24 06:04:48.844-07 ERROR o.d.w.r.HkeyPerformanceDataUtil - Unable to locate English counter names in registry Perflib 009. Counters may need to be rebuilt: 
com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
    at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util.registryGetStringArray(Advapi32Util.java:951)
```

The registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009 exists but has no content. On a non container I see various keys there but in a vanilla Windows servercore: ltsc2019 container the key is not there.

There are several article from MS on how to rebuild the performance counters although non are specific for the Windows Server 2019.

I find it strang that I need to rebuild something on a fresh container. Am I missing something obvious or is there another way to get the azure application insights Java agent to work in a container?

If I just export the registry key from a Windows Server 2019 and import that into the registry of the Windows running in the container everything seems to work fine, no more errors. Still don't understand why this is necessary.

Comment: Same issue here in mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019 when import insights java agent to my Spring application.

Answer (score 0):

As the author of the application causing your log message above, I just found about this as the result of another user [experiencing this issue](https://github.com/oshi/oshi/issues/1976). I was able to track down an issue in [Azure Application Insights](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/676) that seems to be related.  From the conversation there, it appears that isolation of the container prevents access to the OS.

A suggested workaround is to:

> Add a line to the Dockerfile and grant permissions to the IIS executing user.
>
> `RUN net localgroup 'Performance Monitor Users' /add 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that gave this error: "There is no such global user or group: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool." Note that I'm using the plain windowservercore image and the issue you linked seems to use a different container for dotnet. I tried to reproduce the original issue and I can with AI agent 3.1.1 but not with 3.2.8 or at least the error is not visible in the log anymore. You should be able to reproduce it with the code from: https://github.com/robbie-coder/ai-container-perfcount-issue replace the AI key in the Dockerfile for your real one. Error shows after a few minutes.